# What is AdMob error TCF 7.8 for my Android App?

Tags: android, admob, ads, gdprconsentform

On AdMob web site I just saw an error concerning an ad banner in my [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Cyrille%20Fougerouse) (niveau de la version 2.0 du TCF de l'IAB)
The error is 7.8 which means:
TC string version field is neither 1 nor 2.

Only limited ads will be served. CMP should fix the TC string implementation errors.

What is it ?

The [error](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9999955) is under this text:

Google will handle issues
When these issues occur, Google will mitigate the problem, itself, when necessary and proceed with normal TCF handling.

But it's weird, since beginning of January my income have decrease a lot, is it link to GDPR ? What can I do ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**

### Google will handle this issue.

**

Google has announced that it will actively address issues with error codes starting from 7.X, including error 7.8. if you see the error 7.8 in AdSense or in AdMob just wait. Typically, the message should disappear on its own once the issue is resolved by Google.

So, I guess that you can ignore the warning and that Google will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CMP consent from Google?
If so, it is Google's responsibility to [fix this error](https://boostadrevenue.com/how-to-fix-tcf-error-78-adsense/).
If I were you, I'd wait for more information from Google. So far, no one has written anything.

There are few advertisers in January. Your income may be low due to low competition in the AdSense ad auction. October-December is a huge increase in earnings - the holiday season.

Comment: ok thanks. I saw in adMob settings that I can add 'Personalized advertising partners', do I need to select more than the 190 default ones ? (Limited to 700)

Comment: During my App upload, Google said that my App did not include the permission : com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID which is false, it is included, do you think that it can be an issue about low income ?

Comment: I would have to analyze the domain with my tool.